# Dagger Component.Factory cannot be provided

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have a `Component` to provide dependencies for Data Input:

```
@Component(modules = [DataInputModule::class])
interface DataInputComponent {
    fun inject(activity: DataInputActivity)

    fun factory(): Factory

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance activity: DataInputActivity, module: DataInputModule): DataInputComponent
    }
}
```

With the module:

```
@Module
class DataInputModule(private val activity: DataInputActivity) {
    @Provides
    fun provideDataInputViewModel(repo: MyRepository, timestampProvider: TimestampProvider) =
        DefaultDataInputViewModel(repo, timestampProvider)

    @Provides
    fun provideTimestampProvider(): TimestampProvider = DefaultTimestampProvider()

    @Provides
    fun provideDateTimeDialogFactory(): DateTimeDialogFactory = DateTimeDialogFactory(activity)
}
```

My application's component looks like so:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        DataListModule::class
    ]
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<MyApplication> {
    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance app: MyApplication): AppComponent
    }
}
```

with the module to provide the trusty Room database and the repository.

When trying to build I get the following error:

> D:\Applications\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApp\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\myapp\di\component\DataInputComponent.java:7:
>   error: [Dagger/MissingBinding]
>   com.example.myapp.di.component.DataInputComponent.Factory cannot
>   be provided without an @Provides-annotated method. public abstract
>   interface DataInputComponent {
>                   ^
>         com.example.myapp.di.component.DataInputComponent.Factory is provided at
>             com.example.myapp.di.component.DataInputComponent.factory()

I cannot add a `@Provides` to the `@Component` because it is not a module. I looked for docs online but found no example of anyone "provides" annotating and providing a `@Factory`. So what could cause the issue here?

Comment: A `component` cannot provide a factory to build an instace of itself. If you already have a DataInputComponent what would you use a DataInputComponent.Factory for? Did you intend to make DataInputComponent a SubComponent of AppComponent and have a DataInputComponent.Factory provided by AppComponent?

Comment: The factory is defined within Component but is not accessed by having a `DataInputComponent` instance. See here: https://dagger.dev/api/2.22.1/dagger/Component.Factory.html I defined the component just like them. Now, the `factory()` method is indeed unnecessary in my case, just added that out of desparation. Without it the same problem persists.

Comment: In general you can't inject `Factory`s of `Components`. You should create the component yourself using `DaggerYourComponentName.Factory().create(...)` and then use the componet to inject/provide objects.

Note that this is different for `Factory`s of `@SubComponent` those can be injected within the scope of their parent `Component`.

Comment: @al3c true, only seen it being used as you say so. But my problem is that my code doesn't even compile; I'm nowhere near actually using it.

Comment: Well if you remove the code where you try to inject `DataInputComponent.Factory` your code should, at least, give a different error.